# How to use all vCPUs with `pytorch`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm training 2 `pytorch` models on a Google cloud instance `n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory)`. In the first case I have only about `50%` utilization (`400%` in the picture below) but in the second case it can be much higher (around `600-700%`). In both cases I'm training `NLP` models with `LSTMs`. How can I increase utilization in the 1st case?

[image: <code>top</code> command screen]